# Yii CGridView hide filter input only

Tags: yii

When using CGridView, the filter input fields are automatically generated by the component.

I want to select which columns will show the input field. For example:
My model has 5 columns. I want CGridView to show the input filter ONLY for columns 1 and 2.

Is there a way to do it without using CSS or jQuery, just adding some code on the CGridView options?

Comment: is it just add: array('name' => 'col 3', 'filter' => false) ?

Comment: You can comment 'filter' => $model to hide all filters too

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
array(
    'name'=>'col3',
    'value'=>'$data->col3',
    'filter'=>false,
)
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all filters form the entire `CGridView`, configure `'filterPosition'=>''`

Comment: It seems like a hack, because it is not documented  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/#filterPosition-detail

Answer (score 0):

Only comments and filter disappears...
example:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'usuario-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
//'filter'=>'false',
'columns'=>array(
    'rut_usuario',
```

....

Answer (score 0):

Setting `'filter'=>false,` is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put 'filter'=> false, but this attribute will minimize the witdh of the column.. another way to disable the filtering on a specific column is to return a input with attribute 'disabled' like:

```
 'filter'=>'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="UsersSearch[password]" 
   disabled>',
```