# Add filter for some columns only in yii tbgridview

Tags: gridview, yii, filter

I'm new in Yii and have problem with TbGridView.

Can I make the gridview to have filter for certain columns only?
for example, I have these grid view:

```
$this->widget( 'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'id'             => 'report-purchase-grid',
        'template'       => "<div>{pager}</div><div style='float:left;'>{summary}</div><div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>\n{items}\n<div>{pager}</div><div style='float:left;'>{summary}</div><div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div><br/>",
        'dataProvider'   => $model->getReport(),
        'selectableRows' => 2,
        'columns'        => array(
            array(
                'name'   => 'months',
                'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'months'),
                'header' => 'Month',
            ),
            array(
                'name'   => 'transaction_date',
                'header' => 'Transaction Date'
            ),
            array(
                'name'   => 'code',
                'header' => 'Purchase Code',
            ),
         ),
)),
```

If I use filter below dataProvider, I will end up have filter in all column. But I only want to have filter in months. I tried using filter below months just like above example, but no luck too.

Does anyone know how to do that? I appreciate it if anyone can tell me.

Comment: Never mind. I already have the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483514/yii-cgridview-hide-filter-input-only

Answer (score 0):

```
'columns'=>array(
      array(
        'name'=>'columnName',
        'visible'=>false
          ),
       )
```